# Pass information between jobs in Quartz.NET

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have two Quartz.NET jobs that run occasionally which I need to pass information between. How do I do this?

Below is an example class for setting the data:

```
[PersistJobDataAfterExecution]
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class PushingJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var keys = context.Scheduler.GetJobKeys(GroupMatcher<JobKey>.AnyGroup());

        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            var detail = context.Scheduler.GetJobDetail(key);
            if (detail.JobType == typeof(PullingJob))
            {
                detail.JobDataMap.Put("Foo", "Bar");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is an example for getting the data:

```
[PersistJobDataAfterExecution]
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class PullingJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo property = " + context.MergedJobDataMap.GetString("Foo"));
    }
}
```

Comment: can it happen that those two jobs run in the same time?

Comment: potentially but unlikely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a DI engine, you can share a single instance object between those two jobs instance, with a concurrent dictionary in it.

Otherwise, you can always share a static concurrent dictionary between them even without the DI engine (less elegant, but it works) :)

For example, with injection:

```
[PersistJobDataAfterExecution]
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class PushingJob : IJob
{
     DataObject _data;

     // with injection
     public PushingJob(DataObject data)
     {
         _data= data;
     }

     public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
     {
        var keys = context.Scheduler.GetJobKeys(GroupMatcher<JobKey>.AnyGroup());

        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            var detail = context.Scheduler.GetJobDetail(key);
            if (detail.JobType == typeof(PullingJob))
            {
                data.MyDict.AddOrUpdate("Foo", "Bar");
            }
        }
    }
}

[PersistJobDataAfterExecution]
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class PullingJob : IJob
{
     DataObject _data;

     // with injection
     public PushingJob(DataObject data)
     {
         _data= data;
     }

     public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo property = " + _data.MyDict.GetOrAdd("Foo"));
     }
}
```